# Low FPS on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, graphics, xubuntu, intel-graphics, opengl

I've Intel G41 Express Chipset, I'm trying to play Minecraft on it but it's having FPS drops. In windows, I used to get like 100 FPS easily. Please provide me some detail about what I can do.

Comment: It would help to know which version of Xubuntu you’re running. Can you update your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a` and `sudo lshw -C video`? This will report the specific version and video hardware used by your computer.

Comment: I'm running focal xubuntu,
`Linux crackpixel 5.4.0-73-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 17:39:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Result for lsb_release -a
```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

Result for lshw
`https://termbin.com/tg35`

Comment: @matigo you there?